# Concatenate two given strings in 8086 + MOVSB does not work

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm trying to write a 8086 assembly program to concatenate two given strings.
In order to do this, I used a "*REP MOVSB*" instruction, but the program didn't work well. So I wrote a program that should statically concatenate two strings, but it seems that "*REP MOVSB*" does not affect on strings at all.
Here's the part of code I wrote for test:

```
                                          
data    segment
    
string1 db  "Lotfi", 0
string2 db  "Ali ", 0 
    
data ends


code segment    

ASSUME  CS: code, DS: data
              
start:
    cld
    mov     ax  , data
    mov     DS  , ax
    
    mov     SI  , offset string1
    mov     DI  , offset string2
    add     DI  , 3 ; Adding the length of destination string to the DI
    
    
    mov     cx  , 5
    rep movsb ; This should concat two strings

    ; Printing the result character by character on the console
    mov     SI  , offset string2
l:  lodsb           ; Printing loop
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 2h
    int 21h
    jmp l
    

    hlt 
    
    code ends
end start
```

The result of the code is something like:

```
Ali             ü,Z0???... (And so)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Random notes: 1) Your loop is infinite. 2) There's no allocated memory after the end of String2. 3) After the concatenation the resulting string isn't null-terminated. 4) Just in case: Are you sure your code operates in a 16bit environment? If it's 32bit you have random garbage in upper 16 bits of all registers.

Comment: Thank you, I considered all of your recommendation in my real program (except the last one about 16 and 32 bit, which I didn't get it!), But here I deleted them all for making it easier to read

Comment: @OndrejTucny considering there are calls to the DOS kernel (int 21h) I think it's safe to assume the code runs in a 16-bit environment.

Comment: @davmac "I have… seen things you people wouldn't believe…" (However, yes it's safe to assume.)

Comment: This method could, theoretically, overwrite data in memory. Better to reserve a buffer in memory, and concatenate the strings in the reserved space.

Comment: Easiest way to do that is to reserve empty space that's larger than the sum of the lengths of both strings. Such as: `string3 db 12 dup (0)` (this reserves twelve bytes of space, each byte contains zero. Your assembler's syntax may vary but many use this wording)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`movsb` moves from DS:SI to ES:DI. You've loaded the DS but not the ES register.

You need only add a single line:

```
cld
mov     ax  , data
mov     DS  , ax
mov     ES  , ax   ; here!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DATA SEGMENT
STR1 DB "Tanay$"
STR2 DB "Patil$"
LEN DB ?
DATA ENDS
CODE SEGMENT
START:ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX
LEA SI,STR1
LEA DI,STR2
MOV AL,"$"
NEXT1:CMP[SI],AL
JZ EXIT
INC LEN
INC SI
JMP NEXT1
EXIT:MOV BL,"$"
NEXT:MOV AL,[DI]
CMP AL,BL
JZ EXIT1
MOV [SI],AL
INC SI
INC DI
JMP NEXT
EXIT1:MOV[SI],BL
MOV AH,09H
LEA DX,STR1
INT 21H
MOV AH,0AH
INT 21H
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
CODE ENDS
END START
```

The output will show in your TASM window